# How to set body for google docs while creating a document through google docs API?

Tags: java, google-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am able to access my google docs for content, for a use case I need to access a document get it's content and paste this content multiple times in another google doc.
But I am unable to create a google doc with initialized content

```
        Document response = service.documents().get(DOCUMENT_ID).execute();
```

This is what I am using to retrieve the document that I need to copy.

```
response.getBody();
```

Gives me the content that I now want to replicate and paste in the new Document created by

```
 Document doc = new Document()
            .setTitle("Not Working!").setBody(response.getBody());
    doc = service.documents().create(doc)
            .execute();
```

setBody reference : [Link](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/docs/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/docs/v1/model/Body.html)
Is there anything that I am doing wrong?

Comment: I've hit this issue just now, did you try and use the drive api instead? `files.create` looks promising. May just need to add the MIME type to `application/vnd.google-apps.document` ...

Comment: ... [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) & [CSV Example](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#java_1) & [Google Bug Report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/126597519)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can't do this.*

#### More Information:

As per the documentation on the `documents.create` method (emphasis my own):

> ### Method: documents.create
>
> Creates a blank document using the title given in the request. ***Other fields in the request, including any provided content, are ignored.***

This is why creating a new document with content is not working. You need to use the `documents.create` method to create a document, which will return the cretaed document, and then use [`documents.batchUpdate`](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate) to update this document with the desired content.

#### References:

- [Method: documents.create | Google Docs API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/create)
- [Method: documents.batchUpdate | Google Docs API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)

Comment: Hey, I thought as much but was struggling with the idea of then been given a function setBody which in effect is useless. Thanks for the resources, will try something other than google docs API.

Comment: Yeah it's the same with the Slides API. I would suggest making a feature request to allow a body to be sent on create, you can do that at [https://issuetracker.google.com](https://issuetracker.google.com).